Does the absence of time traveler tourists at historical events make it almost certain that time travel is impossible?
They could hide anywhere on Earth for the moon landing, but you'd think that if time travel was possible, there would be huge crowds at the Declaration of Independence signing and Lincoln's assassination.
And if it were possible, one would think that eventually, a tourist would have altered these horrible events, since it's obviously possible by shooting someone.
Hey, maybe they also figured out how to be invisible, too!


Nah, all the time travellers realized that it was much cheaper to just have already time travelled and then not time travel or even build the time machine, causing an infinite regression that they were will be are having been being sorting out to this very yestermorrow.

Since we know nothing about motivations of time traveler tourists, if any, or technology available to them their absence makes nothing certain or impossible. It does not tell us much of anything at all.

For that matter: How do you know that they are absent?

I dont know. But If time travelers from Earth's future exist and they know about our history, I think it highly likely that they would visit historical events. Obviously, they'd probably try not to interrupt. That we don't see them does, in fact, tell us a set of things, one of which must be possible. Either they're very good at hiding; they're not interested in their own history; or time travel is impossible. Of the 3, I think the third is almost certainly true.

I don't see how this question can possibly be opinion based, since "No, it's not certain, it's opinion based, and I can demonstrate it" would be a verifiable factual answer to "Is it almost certain?"

I don't think timetravel is possible, but that aside, the absence of time travellers could have other reasons.
Maybe human civilisation is not that interesting.
Would you be interested in chimpanzees poking a straw in a termite nest? This was the crowning point of cognitive power before humans arrived on the stage.
Or, alternatively, if you could buy tickets for the meteorite impact that killed the dinosaurs, or the signing of the Declaration of Independence, which would you choose?

@Miss_Understands So, what would your favourite event be to visit ?

@Miss_Understands Not asking for much , are you? Guess if you can travel back in time, being outside space-time is no big deal;)

@Miss_Understands eureka! the triumph of the baryons is because of flash-vaporized time traveling tourists!

There are different models of timelines with time travel in science fiction. One obvious solution is that timelines split on alterations, is that people living in an original timeline do not notice another timeline has been created from such a visit. Also we would not notice if this were a timeline created from a time travel done on another planet in this universe.
So the absence of visitors from the future,  if an absence were provable, would only show something about certain models of time travel for earth.
For other models of single timelines, absence of tourists does not prove theoretical impossibility, only practical impossibility, such as the cost to build a time-machine being too high, despite it being possible.
And indeed as the question shows, absence of evidence is not evidence of absence, so proving no visitors have been to this timeline or changed it can be difficult if they hid very well.
Just to show how far imagination can lead us:
There are also variants less shown in movies, like souls traveling in time (into taget victims), which would be models also for "explaining" alleged reports of reincarnation, or certain personality disorders.

Who knows, maybe in the original timeline humans evolved MUCH slower than desirable, as slow as pseudoscientists calculate the rate of evolution, so once they figured out time travel, they went back and made dna changes, and that perfectly explains intelligent design. If you combine all pseudosciences, it all makes sense

It depends on what assumptions you make about the nature of space and time. Your question is based on an implicit assumption, namely that if at noon you were instantly to travel back to some earlier time, such as 11:55, you would find there the world as it was five minutes ago. However, if you instead adopt the view espoused in most physics textbooks, namely that all objects are continually moving along trajectories in spacetime, what you would find is emptiness, since the world is no longer at the point in spacetime corresponding to 11.55 but has moved on to a different point in spacetime corresponding to 12.00.
That interpretation of time also eliminates the other implicit assumption in your question, namely that there are already people in the future.

A certified time-machine would always sell with a patented spacetime location compensator next to the flux compensator (duh)

Yeah, if you're going to posit the existence of a time machine, part of the definition of time machine is that it's  going to work properly.

You are missing my point. Even if you could go back in time, there would be nothing left there to find.

That’s a pity- I like a good argument!
